# Sapper. How to globally use third-party libraries

Tags: javascript, svelte, gun, sapper

I want to access a variable `gun` in server and client side.

This is my module:

```
import Gun from 'gun/gun'
import Sea from 'gun/sea' // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

export const gun = Gun({
  localStorage: true,
  radisk: true,
  peers: ['http://localhost:8765/gun']
})
```

If it was a `Nuxt`, which I want to abandon in favor of a `Sapper`, I would have implemented it like this:

```
import Gun from 'gun/gun'
import 'gun/sea'
import 'gun/lib/open'

const gun = Gun({
  localStorage: true,
  radisk: true,
  peers: ['http://localhost:8765/gun']
})


export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('gun', () => gun)
}
```

```
// nuxt.config.js
...
plugins: [{ src: '@/plugins/gun.js' }]
...
```

Thus, I would get access to the `$gun` everywhere:

On the server side:

```
export default {
  asyncData(context){
    context.app.$gun()
  }
}
```

And on the client side:

```
  methods: {
    submit() {
      const gun = this.$gun()
      const user = this.$gun().user()
      ...
    }
  }
```

And also in the template:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ $gun }}</div>
</tempalte>
```

This question does not concern the use of the specific library that is being discussed in the question (`gun`). It can be a `Websocet` connection (then we would pass the `ws` variable sun in the same way.), or an rpc (to connect with `Bitcoin`) - I can give many examples where this can be important.

Somewhere I read that you need to implement this through the `rollbar`, somewhere I read about a regular module (`es6` or `.svelte`) - but then I encounter a number of other problems ...

Comment: GUN author here, sorry I don't know much about sapper, looks like (as you mention) this is better for someone else to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the direct question, but I'll just guess... you're trying to use a global variable in svelte (moving from nuxt)?

Svelte uses rollup, and you should have a .rollup.config.js file in your root.

```
export default {
...
    plugins: [
        svelte({ 
           // magic happens here
        })
    ]
}
```

More documentation on (what I think your issue is) including globals.
https://svelte.dev/docs#Compile_time 
& 
https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-svelte

Comment: My question was literally the following: how to make `inject` a variable in the client and server environment in `Sapper`, similar to plugins in `Nuxt`.
And so that this variable is available in both `template` and `script`, something like `$var`

Comment: Can you give an example of use?